# Specifying the origin header in postman does nothing when I make a request to an endpoint in my application (javascript and nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, postman, same-origin-policy

I currently have my server file set up like so:

```
export default createServer = (container) => {
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
  const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS || ''
  const allowedOriginsArray = allowedOrigins.split(",").map(item => item.trim());

  const cors = Cors({
    origins: allowedOriginsArray,
    allowedHeaders: [
      'access-control-allow-origin',
      'authorization',
      'Pragma',
      'contact',
    ],
    exposeHeaders: []
  })
}
```

Here, I have origins set to an array of strings from my env file.  (I have checked the cors documentation page, I believe there may be a typo, origins should be origin.  Either way it does not seem to make a difference).

In my postman request, just to test it out, I have set the origins header to "http://www.test.com" (this is not one of the trusted origins i have in my env file).  The requests succeeds when it should fail.  I'm wondering if I am testing this incorrectly in postman or if something in my code is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment on another answer, I think you have it backwards in your mind; Postman can add Origin because Postman is a tool for "faking" http requests sent by browsers, and to not have the ability to add an Origin would make Postman a poor faker. Origin might be used by some servers and Postman having the ability to send an Origin header means that whatever the server does with it, can be tested.

By and large Origin as a browser-to-server communication is little to do with CORS and SOP, which are a security that works in the direction of "server-to-honest-browser". Inclusion of an Origin header on a request may serve to cause a server to respond with CORS headers but you should not hard-link the two concepts because Origin can be sent for non CORS requests too, and CORS wouldn't specifically require any information in an Origin header in order to work

For CORS enabled scenarios the server says (in a response header) which sites are supposed to be using it and an honest browser (like most people have, when they install latest Chrome) decides whether the page on show should be fetching data from the server or not. Imagine a browser is showing delta.com and a script on the page tries to fetch some data from some back end server. Before it actions the request for the data the script wants the browser makes its own request to the server to check if it's OK; this is an OPTIONS request. If the server responds to the OPTIONS saying "only scripts served from acme.com should use me" and the browser isn't showing acme.com, then the browser doesn't perform the request the script on the page wants to do; instead an error appears in the console, because the delta.com script wanted data and the browser decided not to carry out the request after doing a quick "whisper in the server's ear"

A malicious actor using a browser that doesn't care about CORS requests of "please only use me if you're showing a page from acme.com" will be able to use the server anyway. Postman is an example of such a "browser" - it makes requests at your behest and doesn't care about CORS at all. If you were at all interested in making Postman behave like a browser, you should:

- Pretend to be delta.com
- Use postman to issue an OPTIONS to server.com (with an Origin)
- Postman gets the "i only talk to acme.com" response in the A-C-A-O header
- Your own brain decides not to issue the POST request you originally wanted to do, because you've realized you're pretending to be delta.com and the server only talks to acme.com

This would be a more accurate "postman pretends to be like a normal every day browser" iteraction

---

Origin can feed into CORS; the server could have 1000 different sites it is willing to allow requests from. Clearly sending 1000 site names in every response ("please only use me if you're showing a page from acme1.com, or acme2.com or... acme999.com") would make the response headers huge and the browser then has a thousand sites to check through. If the server is intelligent it can use the Origin to drive the response; if the submitted "Origin: acme547.com" is in the allowed list of 1000 sites the server knows of, then the server can send *just that one* acme547.com back in the "please only use me if.." header - it doesn't need to send the other 999 sites too. If the Origin is from delta.com, then it doesn't send a "please only use me.." header at all, causing an honest browser to fail the request

Comment: *"By and large Origin as a browser-to-server communication is little to do with CORS and SOP..."* The [`Origin` header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#origin-header) is CORS-specific, so it has a fair bit to do with CORS. As you say, it's so we don't have to inflate responses unnecessarily (and spread around information that's probably best not spread around).

Answer (score 5):

The Same Origin Policy is enforced by browsers to stop Mallory's Evil Website from sending your browser some JavaScript that will make an Ajax request to your online banking and send your credit history to Mallory.

CORS is used to relax the Same Origin Policy (so that websites can give access to the data you share with them to certain trusted other websites).

Postman is not a browser. You do not use it to visit websites. It doesn't execute JS embedded in those websites. Mallory can't tell it to make HTTP requests. Only you can do that. Postman doesn't need to enforce the Same Origin Policy, so it doesn't.

You can use Postman to make an HTTP request with an Origin header. Your server can then send back an appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. However, Postman won't do anything with it except display it in the list of response headers.

It certainly won't relax the Same Origin Policy because it doesn't enforce it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the information.  So I guess this leads to two follow up questions.  What is the point of using the Origin header in postman then?  How can I tell that the list of specified origins ive made in my application is working correctly through postman?  Is it by looking at the response and checking the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response?

Comment: "Thanks for the response and the information. So I guess this leads to two follow up questions. What is the point of using the Origin header in postman then?" — To test what response you get. That's what Postman is for.

Comment: "Is it by looking at the response and checking the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response?" — Yes

Comment: @ghostagent151 - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and the other `Access-Control-Allow-XYZ` headers (what methods, headers, etc. are allowed).

Comment: Please forgive me there is still somethings I do not understand.  So, If I make a get request with an Origin header of a site I have not specified in my app.  I get the 200 response with the body of the request.  I look at the responses headers and I am seeing a key called "vary" with these values "origin, access-control-request-method, access-control-request-headers". Where should I be looking to confirm whether or not the origin is valid?

Comment: If the Origin is not allowed then the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should either have a value which is not that origin or should be absent altogether. You can [read the manual for `vary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary).

Answer (score 2):

> The requests succeeds when it should fail.

That's a misunderstanding of how the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) work. The request *shouldn't* fail, it's just that the response will or won't include information that a **browser** can use to determine whether to grant access to the information in it to the origin that requested the information. If the response doesn't allow the origin that requested it, the **browser** prevents code from the origin seeing the response.

Postman, not being a browser, doesn't do that (not least because there's no origin for it to test the response against).

You can't enforce this at the server side reliably, because malicious actors would just send your server what they think your server wants. The point is for the server to reply with information telling a browser who can access that information.

The goal isn't to keep the information the server sends back private (that's what SSL and authentication are for). It's to prevent a user's stored authentication information or active session from being used to steal information using taht user's credentials. Here's how it works:

Let's say Alice goes online to Bank B to pay a bill, and while she has that session active she also goes to check on what something costs and visits Malicious Site X to find out. Malicious Site X, hoping that Alice just happens to be a customer of Bank B, sends a request to Bank B's website for (say) Alice's account information. Let's say that request is a perfect mimic of a real request, so Bank B's website happily returns the information — because Alice **does** happen to be signed in with Bank B's site. Oh no!

This is where the SOP comes in. The browser knows that it was code on X's page that requested the information, and knows that it asked for information from Bank B's website. So it checks the response to see if the response specifically says "yes, it's okay to share this with X." Since the response doesn't say that, the browser prevents Malicious Site X from seeing the response and their evil plot to steal Alice's information is foiled.