# API call returns a response in postman but gives me 403 in browser

Tags: ajax, api, postman

[ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO0gy.png)

[postman url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jknAF.png)
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmTve.png)

Postman returns a response, but browser gives me 403. I have attached my postman request, my ajax call as well as the browser error. Any advice is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass credentials. follow this [link](https://developers.gfycat.com/api/#client-credentials-grant) for more information.

Comment: Please write an answer and not include a link, since this link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. While cedric is right, the Authorization header needs to be specified, another issue can cause this as well. Postman does not include an Origin header in its requests (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68380707/1029688). This could cause it to ignore CORS errors that you would normally encounter when making web requests from a browser.